# How do I implement cell function for React-tables Columns array, if the json coming through doesn't have those functions already built in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

when I look at the react-table documentation for the columns array it has a Cell property that is a function. If my json coming through is from the server how do I implement that Cell function?

The json for the columns coming from the server looks like:

```
[
    {
      Header: "name",
      id: "name"
    },
    {
      Header: "age",
      id: "age"
    }
]
```

End result:

```
[
    {
      Header: "name",
      id: "name",
      Cell: props => (
        return props.whatever
      ),
    },
    {
      Header: "age",
      id: "age",
      Cell: props => (
        return props.whatever
      ),
    }
]
```

UPDATE:
Lets say you have this link below
https://codesandbox.io/s/lrn7j5vjrl?from-embed

Within this link he gets the data from the api call and then uses it to display within the data property. Then below he has a hard coded columns array with some properties. My issue that I'm having is my columns array will be coming from the server as well so how would i add a cell property function to the incoming columns array json?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cell field explicitly in the response array like below.

```
AddCell(response) {
  let responseArr = [...response];
  return responseArr.map((ele, i) => {
     let obj = {...ele}
     obj.cell = <RowElement />
     return obj
  })
}
//Please don't do any network call and set state inside constructor because it will re-render all the child component so use componentDidMount to call.
componentDidMout() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(res => {
       const updatedData = AddCell(res.data);
      // Update react-table
      this.setState({
        posts: updatedData,
        data: updatedData.slice(0, 5),
        pages: updatedData.length / 5,
        loading: false
      });
    });
  }
```

Happy Coding friend :)

Comment: where do I call the addcell function? That's the part that's confusing me more than anything.

Comment: Where are you calling the api ?

Comment: Can you please check my updated section inside the original post?